# What does "period" mean at the end of the American phrase?

Tags: phrases, american-english

What does ***period*** mean at the end of a sentence?

For example:

> The stronger your core the easier your YRG(yoga) is gonna get ***period***

I couldn't understand the sentence clearly because of the speaker's American accent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Period in the context that you are referring to is used as an idiom of sorts. It means there is no counter argument.

For example, "Chuck Norris will kick anybody's butt, period."

or

"Abstinence from sex is the best STD prevention, period."

There is usually a pause after the sentence and before the word "period".

Another thing that Americans say instead of "period" is "end of story".

For example,

The stronger your core the easier your YRG(yoga) is gonna get, end of story.

Comment: You are very welcome but I think you meant "now". :-)

Answer (score 15):

'Period' is the puncutation mark known in British English as a full stop. Used as it is in the example, it means that there is no more to be said on the subject.

Comment: thanks a lot Barrie, but in this sentence "period" is used after "is gonna get" so it doesn't make sense to me.I didn't really get your point

Comment: It means ‘The stronger your core the easier your YRG(yoga) is gonna get’ – and that’s it, end of story, no more to be said, no argument, the sentence has come to an end and so has this discussion.

Comment: The origin of this expression is similar expressions where an implied (or explicit) ‘but’ comes after, with another phrase that softens or counteracts the first phrase. Such phrases would be started with a comma, and the ‘period’ (full stop) spoken at the end of the sentence means that no comma and subsequent phrases will be accepted. Consider a dialogue like so: _Person A_ “Abstinence is the best STD prevention there is.” — _Person B_ “True, abstinence is a good way to prevent STDs, but …” — _Person A_ “No, no buts. Abstinence is the most failsafe STD prevention there is, period.”